# Magento Web Service "product.info" error: Product not exists

Tags: ios, web-services, magento

I have a problem with the Magento Web service (Magento ver. 1.6.0.0) in an iPhone application. In fact I can login and have the product list with this code (product list code):-

```
NSMutableString *parameters = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<sessionId>%@</sessionId><resourcePath>%@</resourcePath>", session, @"product.list"];    


NSString *operation=[NSString stringWithString:@"call"];
NSString *xmlNamespace=[NSString stringWithString:storeWsdlLink];
NSString *adress=[NSString stringWithString:storeURL];


NSString *operatorTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ xmlns=\"%@\">%@</%@>\n", operation, xmlNamespace, parameters, operation];

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/adressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
                         "  <s:Header>\n"
                         "    <To xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/adressing\">%@</To>\n"
                         "    <a:Action>http://tempuri.org/IService1/%@</a:Action>\n"
                         "  </s:Header>\n"
                         "  <s:Body>\n"
                         "    %@"
                         "  </s:Body>\n"
                         "</s:Envelope>\n", adress, operation, operatorTag
                         ]; 

ASIHTTPRequest *asiRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adress]];
[asiRequest setDelegate:self];
[asiRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:adress]];
[asiRequest setTimeOutSeconds:30];
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" value:@"Content-Type"];
[asiRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[asiRequest setPostBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

This don't work if I replace "`parameters`" with this:-

```
parameters = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<sessionId>%@</sessionId><resourcePath>%@</resourcePath><sku>%i</sku>", session, @"product.info", 12345];
```

I got a "`Product not exists.`" error message and "`101`" code error.

In some forums, they advice to add a space after the "12345" (SKU of Product) but this doesn't work.

Edit:-
I use PHP to call Magento web service and it works:-

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('xxx/api/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('userName', 'apiKey');
echo json_encode($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.info', 111));
```

So now I'm sure that the problem is in my code.
The problem ( I think ) is the arguments part ( -->  `<sku>%i</sku>`  <-- ), because if I delete this part I'll have the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the "`parameters`" with this statement:-

```
parameters = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<sessionId>%@</sessionId><resourcePath>%@</resourcePath><sku>%@</sku>", session, @"product.info", @"12345"];
```

First of all, SKU must be treated as a string, because that is how Magento treats SKU. Now if you look closely at the definition of the WSDL for this method `product.info` in [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#catalog_product.info), you will find that it needs 5 parameters:-

- Product ID or SKU (required)
- Store View ID or Code (optional)
- List of required / loaded attributes (optional)
- Identifier Type (optional, but this argument is available from Magento version 1.5.1.0)

Now if you provide only the first argument of "**Product ID or SKU**" (which is required), then all the other arguments will be set as `NULL`, when calling this method `product.info`.
There is no fault in such a call, but since the fourth argument has not been specifically mentioned as `"sku"` or `"id"`, so Magento tries to find it out by analyzing the data type of its first argument (whether it is string or integer, and so on). All these analyses takes place in this method `getProduct()` of this class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product`.

So what I think is that you need to put the value of SKU as a string in the `parameters` variable, so that Magento can understand that it is string & so it is the Product SKU.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for replaying, but i tried this before and doesn't work, in php it work with string BUT i SHOULD add a space to SKU ( SKU.' ' ) thats how ( i think ) magento know that's the SKU and not the id.
if you have other suggestions please tell me .

Comment: @MalekRadhouani - SKU is a unique identifier for each Product, whose data type is `string`. So if you are to add a suffix of ` ` (space) to each such SKU, then there must be some other problem with the code. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes i know that but i get this solution from other forums and other people have the same problem as me with the same version of magento (1.6)
And the code given in magento api site work only with the space added, so i think that the probleme is from this version of magento, i'll  search if a bug is declared in magento site, if yes ill tell you, else ill search in my code and give you the solution. 
Thank you.

Comment: @MalekRadhouani - I will also search for any other suitable option, if available; otherwise I will wait for your solution. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: i search in issues list in magento site [link]http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/list/?p=1, but i dont find this issue,
my solution( for iphone ) is to create a php script to call the magento WS WITH the space added to sku value.
examlpe : 

     if($_POST['action']=='login' && isset($_POST['apiUser']) &&    isset($_POST['apiKey']))
    {
     echo ($proxy->login($_POST['apiUser'], $_POST['apiKey'])); 
    }  

so i call this with the desired action, its not an elegant solution but it work for me.

thank you.

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving hello i am working on magento proj. and i have done successfully for listing , and displaying detail from magento live api but i am stuck in update info. from iphone app to magento with them default api can u help me to sort this problem ?

Comment: @Kartik - Please post your question in SO, and someone will surely provide some suggestions and answers.

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving hello Thanx for reply i found the solution for it. Thank you once again.